# pipe spawn nodejs for pg_restore

Tags: node.js, linux, postgresql

I have a database.dump file in S3.
I am trying to download the file and restore it nodejs.

```
    let p1 = spawn("wget", [
        "https://abc.backup",
    ]);
    let p2 = spawn(pgRestorePath, args, {
        stdio: ["pipe", process.stdout, "pipe"],
        env,
    });

    p1.stdout.pipe(p2.stdin);
```

But currently it is not working.
If I try the command

```
wget -O - 'https://abc.backup'  | ./bin/postgres-15.0/pg_restore -h localhost -p 3308 -d mydb -U postgres
```

It works perfectly using above command. I would like to replicate the same behaviour using spawn